# How do i convert a vector into armadillo matrix?

Tags: c++, c++11, armadillo

I have a vector that contains a list of integers. How do i convert that vector into an armadillo matrix with only 1 column and the number or rows as the length of the vector?

```
16080
16086
16245
16253
16260
16900
200000
```

Like this for example.

Comment: The armadillo matrix should simply be a vector where each element is equivalent to a row.

Comment: I need to do something similar to this but the inverse.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29088809/how-do-i-convert-an-armadillo-matrix-to-a-vector-of-vectors/53369056?noredirect=1#comment93614422_53369056

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
mat A = conv_to<mat>::from(your_vector)
```

if your vector is an std vector.